# Angular CLI: component.html is not displaying its contents

Tags: angular, typescript

My angular app is not displaying the app.component.html content on localhost:4200, even though the component tag is included in index.html. The code is compiling correctly without any errors.

I am not sure but i think the issue may be in app.module.ts:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {AppService} from "./app.service";
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [AppService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

As you can see my component has an app.component.html file but it is not being rendered.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AppService} from "./app.service";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'PS4FrontEnd';
  currencyReq: string = "USD";
  value: number = 0;

  currencyResp = {
    name: "",
    value: 0
  };

  constructor(private AppService: AppService) {}

  getCurrency() {
    this.AppService.getCurrencyService(this.currencyReq).subscribe(
      response => {
          let foo;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

Here you can see that my component.html file is not empty, changing the contents of this file has no effect on the final page being rendered at http://localhost:4200/, it still renders blank.

```
<h1> Hello Professor!</h1>
<h2> Welcome to {{title}}!</h2>
<h3> In this component, I've implemented a currency API.</h3>
<h3> Please enter your desired currency below, and I will return it's value to the Dollar</h3>

<hr/>


<br/>
Current currency is {{currencyResp.name}}: <br/>
<br/>
The value of {{currencyReq}} to the dollar is: {{currencyResp.value}}
<br/>
<hr/>

<form (ngSubmit)="getCurrency()">
  City: <input name="currency" [(ngModel)]="currencyReq">
  <button type="submit"> Get Currency Value </button>
</form>
```

**index.html**

and in index.html you can see that the component reference tag is included in the html code, so why isn't it displaying anything?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PS4FrontEnd</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have errors in console?

Comment: No errors at all

Comment: Please show the AppService code.

Comment: @alok you have declare "currencyReq" as string, may I know what values you are assigning? most probably this cause an issues in your html code.